# return type from init methods in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, return-type, convenience-methods

I use the following convenience method structure when writing Objective-C classes:

```
+ (MyClass *) myClass {
    return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}

- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // set-up code here...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Is there any reason why the convenience method should specify return type `MyClass*` instead of `id`? Or the `init` method should specify either return type?

This seems to be a common pattern in Objective-C code. Never really thought about it until now.

Answer (score 4):

The best option would be to return `instancetype` -  a contextual keyword that can be used as a result type to signal that a method returns a related result type.
 Check out [this post on NSHipster.](http://nshipster.com/instancetype/)

Answer (score 3):

I think `instancetype` is now the suggested approach:

```
+ (instancetype) myClass {
    return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}

- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // set-up code here...
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: LLVM will automatically promote `-(id)init...` methods (among others) to `instancetype`. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#related-result-types

Comment: @edelaney05 - Yes, but it won't automatically update his custom `myClass` method's return type.  That's why we don't have to put `instancetype` on the `init` method, but we do on his custom call.

Comment: Just in case anyone wonders, the methods that will return instancetype automatically if "the first word is “alloc” or “new”, and the method is a class method, or the first word is “autorelease”, “init”, “retain”, or “self”, and the method is an instance method."

Comment: yep! We're in agreement. I just was adding clarity as to why you'd elected to use `instancetype` for the class method but not for the initializer.